# Error in int_abline....plot.new has not been called yet, how to put line of best fit?

Tags: r

I'm trying to put a line of best fit on a graph but I'm getting this error

I've already changed the order of where I put "abline(17.147, 7.245)", I've also tried to add plot.new() but that doesn't work

```
print(lm(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$am))
#the coefficients from above are 17.147 and 7.245
q <- qplot(x = wt, y = mpg, data = mtcars, color = am)
q
abline(17.147, 7.245)
```

I expect a line of best fit on my graph

Comment: you are mixing `ggplot` and `plot`(basic) functions, this does not work. Take a look at `geom_abline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are mixing `ggplot` and `plot` functions. Those can't be mixed easily, so just use one plotting style.

solution with `plot`:

```
plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
abline(17.147, 7.245)
```

[image: plot]

solution with `ggplot`

```
q <- qplot(x = wt, y = mpg, data = mtcars, color = am)
q + geom_abline(intercept=17.147, slope=7.245)
```

[image: ggplot]